# Can we user selenium UI Regression Scripts to do performant testing

Tags: performance, selenium, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I need some input from loadrunner/jmeter experts.

- I'm having automation scripts which is written in selenium+ java .
- Can i use same scripts to do performance testing using loadrunner/jemeter.?

why i want do like this : to maintain single code base. if any changes happen so i will able to correct at one place and use it for UI Automation and performance testing.

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium automates browsers that it!

Jmeter is specifically to use for Performance test. to be more specific either stress testing or load testing.

JMeter and Selenium can be used together for load testing of a website. Selenium is used to perform load testing and JMeter is used to measure the performance of the same. One can measure how fast HTML pages take to load, and also check javascript and CSS performances. This is done using a combination of the graphical JMeter interface and some scripting to invoke Selenium code.

Please read more about it [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/jmeter-vs-selenium)

JMeter and Selenium are both used for web application testing. But the main difference is that JMeter is mostly used to test the performance of web applications under load and stress. On the other hand, Selenium is best suited for automation and cross browser testing of a website. Based on what type of testing is necessary for the project, one can choose JMeter or Selenium or integrate both if that serves their purpose.

Comment: thanks for reply,,Is that good approach to use selenium UI test scripts integrate with  jmeter and do loadtesting

Comment: yes, you can measure how your website is really behaving under stress/load. There could be slowness due to high server uses. The links could be broken etc.. it's good to integrate and have an observation.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, it is possible, but [it is not recommended](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/worst_practices/performance_testing/) even by Selenium developers, be informed of the following additional constraints:

1. Browsers are quite resource intensive, for example [Firefox 94](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/94.0.1/system-requirements/) needs 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per instance so you can calculate how much RAM you will need to simulate, say, 100 users.
2. You won't get metrics and [KPIs](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-kpis-part-1-what-are-kpis) normally available as the result of a performance test run

Comment: thanks for reply,, yah that make sense as well system consumption will be very high